# Unity. FindObjectOfType не находит объект базового класса

Tags: c#, unity3d, наследование

Не обращайте внимания на ошибки в коде, пришлось писать с телефона. Вопрос теоретический.
Есть класс Main с большим количеством полей. И есть класс MainTemp, который наследует от Main эти поля.
На сцене у нас присутствует несколько объектов с компонентом MainTemp.
Теперь смоделируем ситуацию, когда нам нужно будет инициализировать объект с компонентом Main.(допустим это будет префаб, на котором уже висит скрипт Main) Обычно делаю это таким способом:

```
public class Main : MonoBehaviour
{
  static Main instance_;
  public static Main Instance 
  {
     get  
     { 
     if (!instance_) instance_ = FindGameObjectOfType<Main>().GetComponent<Main>();
    // далее код не срабатывает, он находит объект со скриптом       MainTemp...
     if (!instance) instance_ =   Resources.Load(“MainPrefab”).GetComponent<Main>();
return instance_;
   }
}


}
```

```
public class MainTemp : Main
{
  private void Start()
  {
  //мы не знаем существует ли объект с компонентом <Main> на   сцене
  Main main = Main.Instance;
  }
}
```

В этом примере, при запуске сцены, находит любой GameObject со скриптом MainTemp... То есть новый объект с компонентом Main создан не будет.
Что-то не понимаю... Может кто-нибудь сможет подсказать варианты такой реализации?
P.S. прекрасно знаю как реализовать связь между объектами и скриптами другими способами, интересует конкретно этот случай.

Comment: `Public` и `Private` пишется с маленькой буквы. И неплохо было оформить код так, чтобы его было удобно читать.

Comment: -aepot, Вы уже делали такое замечание. Сделал по вашим рекомендациям: в самом начале написал «Не обращайте внимания на ошибки в коде». Тут буквы вообще не воспринимаются? Как же тогда отвечать на теоретические вопросы?

Comment: А вы считаете, что кому-то будет удобно разбираться в некрасивом коде без отступов и т.п. с опечатками в регистрах букв и т.д.? Вы может и писали код на коленке, но это не важно для сайта формата вопрос-ответ, где создают (или пытаются создавать) единую *базу знаний*. А потом какой-то новичок в программировании увидит `Private` и `Public` и спросит: "А ПаЧиМу ЭтО С БаЛьШоЙ БуКвЫ. Я Ни ПаНиМаЙу!"

Comment: По вопросу: `В этом примере, при запуске сцены, находит любой GameObject со скриптом MainTemp` - так и верно! Вы ведь наследуете `MainTemp` от `Main`,соответственно любой объект типа `MainTemp` является и объектом типа `Main`. Например, если вот в таком условии: `Obj is Main`, переменная Obj будет иметь тип данных MainTemp, то условие вернет `true`.

Comment: -Максим, да, это естественно. Как можно найти только базовый Main? У меня есть пару идей в голове, но попытки тщетны. Очень хочется разобраться, неужели мы никак не можем это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FindGameObjectOfType здесь не поможет по той причине, что `MainTemp` тоже является `Main`. Соответственно что первое находит, то тебе и возвращает.

Что делать?

Перебирать все обьекты на сцене и проверять их на то что они являются `Main` но не являются `MainTemp`:

```
if ( (gameObject is Main) && !(gameObject is MainTemp) )
{
   мы нашли главный обьект типа Main - gameObject который зайдет внутрь этого условия
}
```

Comment: выглядит не очень оптимизированно

Comment: @Methorn думаешь поиск обьектов через FindGameObject работает не перебором обьектов пока не встретится необходимый?) 

Кроме того это делается 1 раз на старте сцены. Никаких проблем с быстродействием не возникнет.

Comment: Кроме того при желании можно перебирать не все обьекты на сцене а лишь те которые вернет FindObjectsOfType (обджектС!). Что, вобщем-то, будет все тем же перебором всех обьектов на сцене. Только код немного упростится.

Answer (score 0):

> //мы не знаем существует ли объект с компонентом  на   сцене

Почему не знаете? Посмотреть в иерархию религия запрещает?

В первом `if` вы ищете объект на `сцене`! А если не находите то, грузите из ресурсов, но не создаете (`Instantiate`) его экземпляр на сцене, поскольку синглтон этого не может, он не `MonoBehaviour`.

Ну и метод `start` это не `Start`.

Почему сразу не создать `GameObject` с этим скриптом на сцене и не сделать в скрипте статическую ссылку для общего доступа...

```
public class Foo : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static Foo _main;

    public static Foo Main { get => _main; }

    private void Awake ()
    {
        _main = this;
    }

    public void DoSomething () { }
}
```

---

```
public class Sample : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start ()
    {
        Foo.Main.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

И `FindGameObject` и `Resources.Load` это ужасные практики. Ими вообще не нужно пользоваться!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, это самое стандартное решение которое можно придумать в этом случае. Но интересно узнать именно про объекты, которых нет на сцене и которые мы должны подгружать из ресурсов (например какой-нибудь префаб из AssetBundles, которого вообще не существует на момент запуска). Ну и просто для личного интереса - Каким способом мы можем найти скрипт с базовым классом из примера не имея ссылку на него (по простой причине, что его просто может не существовать на сцене). Вопрос больше теоретический, на ‘подумать’...

Comment: @Александр, Из ресурсов ничё грузить не надо, если объект чтото спавнит, у него должно быть поле с ссылкой на префаб указанный в инспекторе. Стандартный синглтон в этом случае не сработает, потому что он не сможет заспавнить объект на сцене, это могут только monobehavior.